# Ubuntu doesn't show up after upgrading on a dual booted Mac mini

Tags: dual-boot, 14.10, mac, refind

I performed software updates on my Ubuntu 14.10 and was prompted for a restart. After the restart it directly boots into the Mac OSX. I have earlier successfully set up a dual boot on Mac mini using rEFInd and it used to show GRUB with Ubuntu by default.

How do I boot into my Ubuntu?

I am kind of worried if I lost my Linux partition and my data with it.

Comment: Have you tried holding down the ALT key as the machine starts up? This may, at least, get you to the rEFInd boot menu.

Answer (score 1):

This happens when the software updater performs a kernel update OR there is otherwise need for new GRUB files to be installed.

When the kernel update is processed, Ubuntu will show "updating GRUB..." I have found that this totally wipes rEFInd... As will an outright GRUB update OR system-level update of MacOS.

So, you will need to do two things... First make sure that csiutils is off in the MacOS... If you made no updates to MacOS since using rEFInd, it most likely is still "disabled". But, if not, you will need to boot into "recovery mode", run a terminal from the top menu, and enter `csrutils disable`... Then reboot normally into MacOS to reinstall rEFInd.

Once there, you will need to open a BASH terminal in MacOS - with your rEFInd USB stick inserted. And, reinstall rEFInd. It will re-detect everything and even add the the new kernel information to the boot options for Ubuntu.

To do this, in BASH terminal, change to the directory where the rEFInd USB is mounted (Usually in the user's */Volumes///refind-install* (or similar depending on the MacOS version and other factors that I never quite figured out)
once there, type `ls` to see the files. You should see "refind-install" OR, depending on your rEFInd version, you might see "install.sh". (usually the first one)

At the terminal prompt, enter `./refind-install`  Or `./install.sh` This will start the install and restore your boot options. You will have to be in "root" mode. So, it will ask for your password before proceeding. I have found that sometimes a leading space is required for the "./ directive to work in MacOS's BASH Terminal. in earlier versions, like pre-10.9 OSX, it doesn't seem to matter.

Once complete, enter `reboot`  and let it cycle through a fresh boot in which you should see the familiar rEFInd boot loader screen.

Worthy of note, is the fact that if you *EVER* 1) update GRUB, 2) Do an OS update on the MacOS, or 3) Reset your PRAM [ctrl-opt-P-R during boot] you will lose rEFInd again. I have had to do this many times with my MacOS/Ubuntu hybrids. So, keep that USB stick handy. It won't be the last time you will need it.

I truly hope you find this answer helpful.

Comment: FWIW, the rEFInd documentation includes a page on this phenomenon: http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/bootcoup.html. (Note that I maintain rEFInd.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a matter of simply changing the order of your Boot Menu.

On Mac -
Turn on or restart your Mac.
Immediately press and hold the <kbd>Option</kbd> key.
Use your mouse or trackpad or <kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>→</kbd> keys to select the volume you want to use.
<kbd>Double-click</kbd> or press the <kbd>Return</kbd> key to start up your Mac from the volume you selected.